# Java - How to go the first item when you add one to the max in a list?

Tags: java

I have 4 directions with ids of `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`. (North,East,South,West)

If I want to turn left i get the current `Id` and minus 1. I think I figured out the algoritm for this.

```
int currentDirection = 1;
currentDirection = (currentDirection - 1) % 4 + 4;
```

If current direction is 1 (North) and I want to go left (minus), I get this result:

```
Result: 4
```

So it's working. Works with all directions. But I can't figure out how to get correct result when I want to go to the righ (plus). I have tried this code. It works if the current direction is `1`, `2` or `4`. But it's not working when current direction is `3` (South)

```
int currentDirection = 3;
currentDirection = (currentDirection + 1) % 4;
```

Will result like this.

```
Result: 0
```

Comment: `currentDirection = currentDirection % 4 + 1` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: are you sure your turning left algorithm works for all the directions?

Comment: Thank you @J.Z, it's working. You answered first. If you write an answer, I will accept it. Otherwise I will accept the first answer.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko you are right. It's not working now. I think I changed the code when I was trying to figure out for the right turning. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right Turn: `currentDirection = currentDirection % 4 + 1`

Left Turn: `currentDirection = (currentDirection+2) % 4 + 1`

Comment: can you add for left turn as well? I need that too now :)

Answer (score 4):

Simply this: `currentDirection = (currentDirection % 4) + 1;`

UPDATE:
I would implement it as follows since I personally find it more readable:

Turn right:

```
nextDirection = (currentDirection == 4) ? 1 : (currentDirection + 1);
```

Turn left:

```
nextDirection = (currentDirection == 1) ? 4 : (currentDirection - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really is more readable, does the job and I upvoted it but I needed to accept @J.Z's answer. Sorry!